# How to parse JSON which Serialize by JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

i am using JsonConvert.SerializeObject and convert object to json but getting json like as :

```
"{\"ID\":5,\"name\":\"czxc\","createdOn\":\"2015-01-17T11:33:39.9213672+05:30\"}"
```

Can any one help me how to Parse this json to right format like as :

```
"{"ID":5,"name":"czxc","createdOn":"2015-01-17T11:33:39.9213672+05:30"}"
```

using c#.Please help me.

Comment: check jso2csharp.com

Answer (score 3):

The backslashes `\` are added by the Visual Studio Debugger, they are not in the actual string.